# Nest JS Command Bus (CQRS) Multi tenancy , Dependency injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, cqrs

I have Nest JS application with typescript. Recently I had to update this application to use multi tenancy where my main requirement is to connect different database based in tenanId (I know multiple database is not the suggested way but that is my requirement). To achieve this I created one middleware with scope request as below.

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class DatabaseMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private dbConnection: DataSource | null = null;

  constructor(private readonly tenancyService: TenancyService,
    private readonly logger: WinstonLogger) {

  }

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: any): Promise<void> {

    // Logic to get db connection
    this.dbConnection = await this.executeDbMiddleware(req);

    next();

    // close this dynamic connection after request has been executed.
    res.on('finish', async () => {
      if (req['dbConnection']) {
        await req['dbConnection'].destroy();
        req['dbConnection'] = null;
        this.dbConnection = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now I have created one DB Connection provider to read the connection from request, This is also request scope.

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class DbConnectionProvider {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}

  getConnection(): DataSource {
    if (this.request['dbConnection']) {
      return this.request['dbConnection'];
    }

    const connection = getConnectionManager();
    return connection.get();
  }
}
```

I have repository as below

```js
@Injectable()
export class StateRepository implements IStateRepository {
  constructor(private readonly dbConnectionProvider: DbConnectionProvider) {}

  private get connection(): DataSource {
    return this.dbConnectionProvider.getConnection();
  }

  private get stateRepository(): Repository<States> {
    return this.connection.getRepository(States);
  }

  public async save(state: States): Promise<States> {
    return await this.stateRepository.save(state);
  }
}
```

All of this flow is working fine with my API's, But my few API have Command bus, And Whenever API calls command handler my repository and service are getting undefined at constructor level, Please find one of command handler as below.

```js
@CommandHandler(SomeCommand)
export class SomeCommandHandler
  implements ICommandHandler<SomeCommand>
{
  constructor(
    private _logger: WinstonLogger,

    private _stateRepository: StateRepository,
  ) {}

  async execute(command: any): Promise<boolean> {
    this._logger.info(
      `At command handler`,
    );

    const state = await this._stateRepository.getById(command.id);
  }
}
```

I am triggering command from my service layer as below

```js
await this.commandBus.execute(
    new SomeCommand(clientId, savedClientGoal, user)
);
```

I have tried creating custom context. and few other option, but no luck.
Any suggestion to get dependency resolved and get req object for command handler would be appreciated.

Thanks